# Is it possible to pick out an item from a list of widget's based on the widget's value in dart / flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of `PopupMenuItem<T>` as part of `showMenu` and I need to access the `key` for any given item when its clicked.  When you click on an item, the `showMenu` will give you the selected `value`.

So I first gave each `PopupMenuItem` a key, which is part of a `List`:

```
[
   PopupMenuItem<int>-[<'Small'>], 
   PopupMenuItem<int>-[<'Medium'>], 
   PopupMenuItem<int>-[<'Large'>]
]
```

OR put another way:

```
            items: [
                PopupMenuItem<int>(
                  key: ValueKey('Small'),
                  value: 10,
                  child: Text('10'),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem<int>(
                  key: ValueKey('Medium'),
                  value: 20,
                  child: Text('20'),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem<int>(
                  key: ValueKey('Large'),
                  value: 30,
                  child: Text('30'),
                ),
            ],
```

Now when you tap on an item, or select an item you get returned the `value` of that item, which is great, but I want to get access to the `key`, which is the `Small`, `Medium` and `Large` listed above.

So is there a way to dive into a given list and get the item  based on its `value`.  If I have the `item` or at least its `position` in the list I can then get the `key` by doing :

```
((items[1].key) as ValueKey<String>).value.toString(); 

/// 1 represents the position in the list.  
///That is what I need to try to get, or just get the whole item somehow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using UniqueKey() for the key. You can build a simple solution for your use case.

You can have a map to store the values with the respective strings.

```dart
Map<int,String> data ={10, 'Small', 20: 'Medium', 30: 'Large' }
```

Once you get the value from the tap, you pass the value to the map to get the respective string:

e.g. data[value]

simple and fast